# Jquery load page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple website http://cone.hostei.com/index3.html using jquery. I just want to load html pages into a div using `.load()` function. The problem is that functions - `$('.preloader').hide()` and (`{ opacity : 1 }`),  fire before page and its images are fully loaded into a div! how  can I fix it?

```
$(window).load(function () {
 $('li a').click(function () { //event on click
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href'); //get href of a li element
    $('.load-in').fadeOut('fast', loadContent);
    $('.loader').show(); //show the loader


    function loadContent() {
        $('.load-in').css({ //set opacity 0.3
            opacity: 0.3
        }).load(toLoad, hideLoad); //load html page, then callback
    };


    function hideLoad() {
        $('.load-in').fadeIn('fast',

        function () { //hide preloader and set opacity 1
            $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.load-in').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        });
    };
    return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. No offence, the code is poorly structured on your page as well. It's very hard to decipher what your intent is.

Comment: you need to copy the relevant code to the question, not just a link to a web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect when the images are fully loaded so that you don't see them appear after the content was shown, you will have to attach a `load` event handler on all images contained in the `.load-in` element and wait before all the images are loaded before fading in the element and fading out the loading indicator.

Something like this (based on code from your site):

```
function loadContent() {
    var $loadIn = $('.load-in');

    $loadIn.css({ opacity : 0.3 }).load(toLoad , function () {
        var $images = $('img', $loadIn),
            imageCount = $images.length,
            loadedCount = 0;

            //wait on images before showing the content
            $images.on('load', function () {
                if (++loadedCount === imageCount) {
                    $images.off('load');
                    hideLoad();
                }
            });

           //make sure the content is still shown if images fails to load
           //or are very slow to load
           setTimeout(function () {
               if (loadedCount !== imageCount) {
                   $images.off('load');
                   hideLoad();
               }
           }, 5000);
    });   
};
```

However, here's some things you should know (taken from http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> > Caveats of the load event when used with images A common challenge
> >     developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a
> >     function when an image (or collection of images) have completely
> >     loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be
> >     noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the    same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: Thx a lot for your help, I Am a rookie in Jquery, if it woun't trouble you much, could you show how to do it?!

Comment: @user2264246, well I just did in my answer, however I have not tested but that's the idea.

Comment: @user2264246, so you tried my solution and it's not working? Do you get any errors or it doesn't give the expected result?

Comment: Sorry! Maybe I', blind or something, but I can't find ACCEPT button here! I see only ACCEPTED in your message above, that's it! Maybe it's browser issue!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to put your jQuery code inside the $(document).ready() handler.  This will make sure your code runs after all elements in the page have been loaded.

See the jQuery API page:  [jQuery - .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: It's already in a `window.load` on his page. Look at the code.

Comment: That is not the issue at all. Read the question.